# PHP invoke method using string for method name

Tags: php, methods, reflection

I would like to have an array of methods in my php class, indexed with method names, so that I can do something like this:

```
public function executeMethod($methodName){
 $method=$this->methodArray[$methodName];
 $this->$method();
 // or some other way to call a method whose name is stored in variable $methodName
}
```

I've found this for __call:

> The overloading methods are invoked when interacting with properties
>   or methods that have not been declared or are not visible in the
>   current scope

However, methods I'd like to use in executeMethod are visible.

What is proper way to do that? Is it possible?

EDIT: I wanted to get a method name in the executeMethod, and then call the method of the given name, and had an idea of methods array.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Can you show what `$this->methodArray` contents look like? How does the value differ from the key?

Comment: I didn't know how to call methods, but thanks to answers below, I figured it out. I wanted something like this: $methodArray = (methodName=>method), but having read that I can call methods by using string, I made it work. : )

Comment: **See also** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458840. This question addresses the former title of this question "how to get methods into an array". The answers in this post never addressed this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call object methods and properties by using string with syntax

```
$method = 'your_method_name_as_string';
$this->$method();
```

from [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    function Variable()
    {
        $name = 'Bar';
        $this->$name(); // This calls the Bar() method
    }

    function Bar()
    {
        echo "This is Bar";
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$funcname = "Variable";
$foo->$funcname();  // This calls $foo->Variable()

?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that I can call methods with string variables. Now I don't need an array of methods. You helped me a lot! : )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
public function executeMethod($methodName) {
    if (isset($this->methodArray[$methodName])) {
        $method = $this->methodArray[$methodName];
        return call_user_func(array($this, $method));
    }
    throw new Exception("There is no such method!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) are available in php 5.3

i think you're trying to do something like

```
$tmp['doo'] = function() { echo "DOO"; };
$tmp['foo'] = function() { echo "FOO"; };
$tmp['goo'] = function() { echo "GOO"; };

$tmp['doo']();
```