# Get Names from get_class_methods(), but in which order?

Tags: php, php-5.6, php-7.1

Like this sample from PHP manual, get_class_methods() get all the functions names.

```
<?php

class myclass {
    // constructor
    function myclass()
    {
        return(true);
    }

    // method 1
    function myfunc1()
    {
        return(true);
    }

    // method 2
    function myfunc2()
    {
        return(true);
    }
}

$class_methods = get_class_methods('myclass');
// or
$class_methods = get_class_methods(new myclass());

foreach ($class_methods as $method_name) {
    echo "$method_name\n";
}

?>
```

Result :

```
myclass
myfunc1
myfunc2
```

But is this order guaranteed or not? I need absolutely this coded order.

EDIT 1

```
foreach ($class_methods as $method_name) {

    $aProp = $$myclass->$method_name();
    [...]   
}
```

EDIT 2

This class contained a lot of metadata. To work in this order .

```
class metadata {

  public function COMPANY() {
    return array ( 'pos' => 1,
                   'feldname' => 'COMPANY'
                  );
  }
  public function BOOK_CIRCLE() {
    return array ( 'pos' => 2,
                   'feldname' => 'BOOK_CIRCLE'
                  );
  }
  [...]
 }
```

Any better idea?

Comment: Yes...It will shows in this order..

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I build a class with function and the function are need to executed in this coded order.

Comment: yes the order will follow from top-to-bottom:-https://eval.in/840528  AND  https://eval.in/840529

Comment: @twyly The functions will be executed in the order you call them. You want to call them automatically?

Comment: I certainly wouldn't rely on this - I suspect bytecode caches or class inheritance could potentially interfere with it. If you need to execute methods in a particular order, then call them in that order, don't rely on the file structure.

Comment: @Twinfriends Yes, I will do some like EDIT 1 show above

Comment: Well, I don't know what you're trying... but I don't think that its really "OOP" what you're doing here...

Comment: @Twinfriends My classes looks like EDIT 2.